# Difference between drawing via CGContext functions(CGContextAddArc, etc) vs CGPath functions(CGPathAddArc, etc)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I know that if you draw with CGPath functions you would have to add that CGPath to CGContext in the end anyway(CGContextAddPath), but **is there any advantage/disadvantage choosing first method over the second?** And yes, I know that you can draw with UIBezierPath as well, and I know the difference between CGPath.

Answer (score 1):

So, going through the documentation on UIBezierPath I bumped into one of the advantages of drawing via CGContext functions:

> The advantage of modifying the graphics context (as opposed to the path object itself) is that you can easily undo the transformation by saving and restoring the graphics state. [UIBezierPath documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW1)

Another one I came up with is that you don't have to release the path(CGPathRelease) if you draw via CGContext functions.